# Declaring XML in SQL Server issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a T-SQL issue, I am trying to do the following and I receive an error message when I try to run the `SELECT` statement, saying that I didn't declare the `@Xml` variable, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = N'
 <products>
 <product id="1" name="Adjustable Race" />
 <product id="879" name="All-Purpose Bike Stand" />
 <product id="712" name="AWC Logo Cap" />
 <product id="19910" name="Cozonac" />
 </products>';

SELECT 
    xt.xc.value('@id', 'INT') AS ProductID,
    xt.xc.value('@name','NVARCHAR(50)') AS Name
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('/products/product') AS xt(xc);
```

Comment: Working for me in SSMS.  Are you sure you are running the entire thing (the declare and the select) in one go? IN SQL Fiddle it works if I take out the separating semi-colon. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27396)

Comment: Works just fine for me. You don't happen to have a `GO` delimiter between the declaration of `@Xml` and the `SELECT` by any chance??

Comment: @marc_s, I think the comma got lost in an edit, it was there when I copied it.

Comment: @Andrew: in fact, it did - I added it back (since the OP had it in there in the first place)

Comment: thank you guys, it my was my bad as Andrew said, should have ran the whole thing, @mark_s - I didn't have a GO in between, just didn't select the full statement DECLARE + SELECT, thanks again :-)

Answer (score 3):

Declaring and directly assigning a value to a parameter is new.
In previous versions of SQL Server, you should first declare and then as a seperate statement set the value of it.
Perhaps you can try

```
DECLARE @Xml XML
SET @Xml = N'...'
```